# Escaping JSON and Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I need a json-string to be used in a regex. Honestly I am a bit confused about all the escaping.. :)

I want to replace "\o/" by something else by regex. The source string should be in a JSON.

This is the JSON-String without escaping:

```
var emoticons=...
    + '{"img": "party.png","short": "\o/"},'
...
```

I tried to escape the slash and backslash to meet the regex' need but after that wasn't able to parse the JSON anymore:

```
var emoticons=...
    + '{"img": "party.png","short": "\\o\/"},'
...
```

How should the JSON-String look like?

Code:

```
var smilies = JSON.parse(emoticons);
text.replace(new RegExp(smilies.short,......);
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't apply the regex to the entire json string; parse the json, find the variable you want and only then apply the regex to the actual string; let your json serializer do the rest.

Comment: I did. It was just about the "short" property

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex)

Comment: @DeanTaylor No. It was not "Just" about escaping a regex but the combination regex/json ("double-escaping")

Comment: @OleAlbers it's a string, it doesn't matter that it is JSON, other than the input to the escaping is a JSON string, ultimately just a string to escape into the RegEx.

Comment: @DeanTaylor I added the code, which should make it clearer. (But is solved nonetheless)

Comment: If you solved it, you should answer your own question, and accept it.

Comment: I hate answering myself, looks like clapping on my own shoulder... :) But well. did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: The string would be `"\\\\o\\/"`